# Surface area and volume of an irregular frustum

Tags: euclidean-geometry, volume, surfaces, solid-geometry

I'm dealing with the following frustum:
[image: Frustum]

Which is similar to a truncated pyramid but the lateral faces may have different inclinations (i.e. $\alpha \ne \beta$). How can I evaluate its volume and lateral surface area? Thank you in advance!

P.S.: Sorry I couldn't provide a 3D sketch, but I hope it's clear from the views above.

Comment: For volume see [prismatoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prismatoid). The area can be easy enough for you to calculate face by face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the lateral area, use the following property:

In 3D space, if a planar polygon (it can be a more general shape in fact, but we don't need it) belonging to a plane $(P)$ with area $A$ is orth. projected  onto a plane $(P')$, making an angle $\alpha$ with initial plane $(P)$, the resulting polygon has area

$$A'=A \cos \alpha \tag{1}$$

The lateral area is obtained by using (1) in a reverse way (= "unprojecting"):

$$\text{lateral area} = \text{area}(R)+2 \ \text{area}(T_1)/\sin(\alpha)+2 \  \text{area}(T_2)/\sin(\beta)$$

where $R$ is the area of the rectangle and $T_1$ and $T_2$ the two projected trapezoids (the area of a isosceles trapezoid being $\frac12(b_1+b_2)\times h$: average base length times height).

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: Thank you Jean Marie! Now suppose the sides on the planes $zy$ and $zx$ are given by some unknown function $z=f(y)$ and $z=f(x)$. How can I state the surface area/volume for any of those functions? Thanks!

Comment: For such a case, always for lateral surface area, you have to "unfold" your surface, meaning at least in the case of a surface projected onto a rectangle that you have to compute the length of the curve by formula $\int_0^b \sqrt{1+z^2}dx=\int_0^b \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$ and multiply it by the width ; in the case of a surface projected onto a trapezoid, it is more complicated but can hopefuly be addressed by a double integral. I will look for references.

Comment: Thank you very much Jean Marie, later I'll have to find the function that extremizes a functional that depends on both this surface area and volume. I'll wait for you references.